# Verificar si un correo electrónico realmente existe o no c#

Tags: c#

Tengo esta función

```
public void checkMail2(string correo)
       {
           try
           {
               TcpClient tClient = new TcpClient("gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", 25);
               string CRLF = "\r\n";
               byte[] dataBuffer;
               string ResponseString;
               NetworkStream netStream = tClient.GetStream();
               StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(netStream);
               ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();

               dataBuffer = BytesFromString("HELO KirtanHere" + CRLF);
               netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
               ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
               dataBuffer = BytesFromString("MAIL FROM:<YourGmailIDHere@gmail.com>" + CRLF);
               netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
               ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();

               dataBuffer = BytesFromString("RCPT TO:<" + correo + ">" + CRLF);
               netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
               ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
               if (GetResponseCode(ResponseString) == 550)
               {
                   Console.Write("Correo no existe");
                   Console.Write("texto:" + ResponseString);
               }

               dataBuffer = BytesFromString("QUITE" + CRLF);
               netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
               tClient.Close();
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(e);
           }

       }
       private byte[] BytesFromString(string str)
       {
           return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
       }
       private int GetResponseCode(string ResponseString)
       {
           return int.Parse(ResponseString.Substring(0, 3));
       }
```

Y funciona correctamente con correos gmail, pero quisiera poder validar cualquier dominio, que sea gmail, hotmail, yahoo. Alguien sabe las direcciones SMTP de los otros servidores?

Comment: vos estas seguro que funciona?? puedes verificar que existe una cuenta que no es tuya?

Comment: si, ya hice pruebas con gmail.com y si funciona, pero no puedo con correos hotmail

Comment: buscaste las direcciones SMTP por google? esto parece mas algo que google sepa, mas que alguien se las acuerde de memoria.

Comment: Utilicé esta smtp-mail.outlook.com
pero me marca el el errror 530 de SMTP

Answer (score 1):

Siempre recuerda que `dig` es tu amigo en todo lo que tenga que ver con nombres de dominio. Para encontrar servidores de correo tienes que buscar registros `MX` o Mail Exchange:

```
yorom@CT100:/tmp$ dig mx hotmail.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> mx hotmail.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21738
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 75

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;hotmail.com.                   IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
hotmail.com.            2520    IN      MX      5 mx4.hotmail.com.
hotmail.com.            2520    IN      MX      5 mx1.hotmail.com.
hotmail.com.            2520    IN      MX      5 mx2.hotmail.com.
hotmail.com.            2520    IN      MX      5 mx3.hotmail.com.
```

y *tropecientos* servidores más. Para Yahoo debe funcionar con lo mismo.

Comment: entonces como dirección SMTP utilizo cualquiera de los 4 resultados?

Comment: Esos son los servidores que reciben correos a cuentas `@hotmail.com`. Prueba con cualquiera de ellos

Comment: enterado, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Queria darte un comentario pero no puedo, pero te puedo recomendar que cheques este [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5189/End-to-end-Email-Address-Verification-for-Applicat)
aquí dice como validar con servidores SMTP o SMTP VRFY.

Comment: Gracias Santigo, pero ya probé esa app y no me funciona, sabes la razón?

Comment: Ya has probado verificando que todos los complementos de salida c# los tengas instalado ?

Comment: si, de hecho descargué el .zip que tiene la publicación

Comment: Esta raro, yo lo probé y si me funcionó pero deja revisó mi código a ver si no hice ningún cambio

Comment: Muchas gracias Santiago, igual si te funciona y si te es posible, pasarme tu proyecto, claro si no es mucha molestia

Comment: Claro nada más verificó si cambie algo y te aviso si no pues ya te envío mi proyecto

Comment: Raios tengo un problema no puedo abrir mi proyecto me fallo el visual, pero dentro de la carpeta de mi proyecto tenia guardado una nota con este link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5O6rtkeozY
 eso me ayudo a mi

Comment: Muchas gracias Santiago